# Image not displaying in spring-mvc

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to display image on index.jsp in spring-mvc app but not able to find the actual path to the image i have added **mvc:resources** tag with correct path but still image is not getting displayed. Here is my code.

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="in.net.usit"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lts2d/lts2dnew"></property>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="in.net.usit.beans"></property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect" >org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql"> true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hb2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean  id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/img/"/>
    <!-- <mvc:default-servlet-handler /> -->
```

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
 
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var module = angular.module('myApp', []);
 module.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  console.log('inside the index page');
 });
</script>



<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body >
 <%-- <img src="<c:url>/img/ImgPitSide.png"</c:url> --%>
 <img src="<c:url value='/img/ImgPitSide.png'/>"/>
 </body>
</html>
```

indexController.java

```
package in.net.usit.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import in.net.usit.service.LadleLocationServiceImpl;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

  private LadleLocationServiceImpl ladleLocationService;

 @RequestMapping(value="/main",method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public String getIndexPage(){
    System.out.println("Inside the controller ");
    return "index";
   }

}
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: try like this <img src="<c:url value='/resources/ImgPitSide.png'/>"/>

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt same results

Comment: use self-closing tag <mvc:annotation-driven />

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt same results also the link i for the image show correct path but does not load the image

Comment: there is no error on the console?

Comment: WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/DynamicImage/resources/ImgPitSide.png] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt -any suggestions please? i have tried almost everything here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142481/discussion-between-gurkan-yesilyurt-and-sumit-amble).

Answer (score 0):

If you have    `/webapp/resources/ImgPitSide.png`

So, you can access like this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

<img src="<c:url value='/resources/ImgPitSide.png'/>"/>
```